# Delete files older than X days +

Tags: files, find, rm, timestamps

I have found the command to delete files older than 5 days in a folder

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

But how do I also do this for subdirectories in that folder?

Comment: Do you mean files inside the sub directories? or the sub directories themselves?

Comment: `find /path/to -type d -empty -delete`

Comment: Delete files in subdirectories that are also 5+ days old

Comment: Possibly fun when I have files with spaces. E.g a file called "test one" and rm gets fed `rm test one`.  (Which will delete a file called "test" and a file called "one", but not a file called "test one").  Hint: -delete or -print0

Comment: As a side note, **always quote the argument provided by `find`** to avoid issues with special characters, as mentioned in the answer's first line. E.g.: `find /path/to/files/ -exec somecommand '{}' \;`

Comment: @Walf The only reason one would want to quote `{}` is if one's shell treats that 2-character string specially. I believe `(t)csh` does this, but no other shell that I know of. You don't have to quote `{}` in e.g. `bash`, no matter what filenames you come across. The POSIX standard guarantees that each found pathname will be given to the utility as a separate argument.

Comment: @Kusalananda or if you're writing a command that may end up getting executed in another shell like `fish`. Don't make assumptions, better safe than sorry, etc. Makes it obvious that it's an argument to `find`, like when you have to quote glob patterns inside `-name` (and related) arguments.

Comment: The easiest way is the below . You can first check the file names count with the below for the last 2 months , then verify and check , then delete the files .

find . -iname "*.gz" -mindepth 1 -mtime +60 | wc -l 

Then check the files 
find . -iname "*.gz" -mindepth 1 -mtime +60 -print 

Once verified you can delete the same .
find . -iname "*.gz"  -mindepth 1 -mtime +60 | xargs rm -f

Answer (score 407, accepted):

Be careful with special file names (spaces, quotes) when piping to rm.

There is a safe alternative - the **-delete** option:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +5 -delete
```

That's it, no separate rm call and you don't need to worry about file names.

Replace `-delete` with `-depth -print` to test this command before you run it (`-delete` implies `-depth`).

Explanation:

- `-mindepth 1`: without this, `.` (the directory itself) might also
  match and therefore get deleted.
- `-mtime +5`: process files whose
  data was last modified 5*24 hours ago.

Comment: Also use `-type f` to delete files only (and keep sub directories)

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to do the same for all files NEWER than five days: find /path/to/directory/ -mindepth 1 -mtime -5 -delete

Comment: If my path contains spaces how should I do it? `find /path/to/dir\ with\ spaces/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +5 -delete`?

Comment: @uom-pgregorio I would suggest putting the path in quotes.

Comment: I have a cronjob running once a week to delete those scratch files than inevitably accumulate on the disk: ``find /path/to/scratch/space -mtime +60 -print -delete``. So from time to time cron emails me telling me which files I just lost ...

Comment: The timestamp of a folder might be older than the timestamp of file within a subfolder of that folder, i.e. in `/a/b/c.txt`, ``c.txt`` could be young and `a` old (in terms of mtime). And ``find`` could potentially find only one of them (assuming `-mindepth` is not set). However, `-delete` will not delete non-empty folders.

Comment: not on Solaris.

Comment: find /path/to/directory/ -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;  <<- would be a SunOS version. -mindepth also doesn't work there.

Comment: Note that every `find` argument is a filter that uses the result of the previous filter as input. So make sure you add the -delete as the last argument. IE: `find . -delete -mtime +5` will delete EVERYTHING in the current path.

Comment: With option `-mmin` in place of `-mtime`, you can specify time in terms of minutes.

Comment: There is no issue with using `-exec rm {} \;`.  The pathname of the argument will be properly delimited by `find`, no matter what the filename is. It is _not_ "piping to `rm`".  This answer resolves the issue, not by using `-delete`, but by using a directory path as the initial search path instead of a bunch of file paths (this is not even mentioned in the answer).

Comment: unix `find` command is indeed a very _powerful_ tool

Comment: I found that `-delete` will work with very large lists of files, whereas `-exec rm {} \;` can fail if the list of matches is too long.

Answer (score 23):

Note that this command will not work when it finds too many files. It will yield an error like:

```
bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long
```

Meaning the exec system call's limit on the length of a command line was exceeded. Instead of executing rm that way it's a lot more efficient to use [xargs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs). Here's an example that works:

```
find /root/Maildir/ -mindepth 1 -type f -mtime +14 | xargs rm
```

This will remove all files (type f) modified longer than 14 days ago under /root/Maildir/ recursively from there and deeper (mindepth 1). [See the find manual for more options](http://www.thelinuxlink.net/lvlinux/resources/commands/find.html).

Comment: Per @AfshinHamedi's answer on AskUbuntu (https://askubuntu.com/questions/589210/removing-files-older-than-7-day), be careful with files containing newlines and special characters. Instead use `find /root/Maildir/ -mindepth 1 -type f -mtime +14 -print0 | xargs -r0 rm --`

Comment: Or just add '+' to the find results

Answer (score 13):

It's the same. You just have to provide the parent directory rather than the prefix of files. In your example, it would be:

```
find /path/to -type f -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

This will delete all the files older than 5 days which are under `/path/to` and its sub-directories.

To delete empty sub-directories, refer to @Costas comment above.

Comment: Note that for each and every file you will execute the rm command. If you have 1000 files older than 5 days then rm will get started 1000 times. For this reason consider the -delete option as in Costa's comment or -exec rm {} \+

Comment: @Hennes: -- 1) not sure you need to escape `+` in that case. -- 2) better to write `-exec rm '{}' +` to fend off the evil of files with special characters (spaces, newlines, etc...) in their name.

Comment: Note that with `-exec rm {} +`, if there are too many files, `rm` may complain: `Argument list too long`. So yes, `-delete` does seem like the much more sensible option.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the current author of *rawhide* (*rh*) (see https://github.com/raforg/rawhide).

It probably makes the most sense to delete empty directories after deleting files that are older than X days. The modification time of directories is when entries were added or deleted from them. Deleting old files will update the modification time of the directory that contained them to the time of the deletion. So, you don't want to refer to the modification time of the directories themselves. Just delete empty directories. Deleting files at least 5 days old, and then deleting the resulting empty directories can be done with:

```
rh -UUU /path/to 'f && old(5*days)
rh -UUU /path/to 'd && empty'
```

`-UUU` unlinks/removes/deletes the matching files.

The rest is the search criteria.

`f` matches regular files.

`old(5*days)` matches files modified at least 5 days ago.

`d` matches directories.

`empty` matches empty directories (and regular files of zero size).

It can also be done with find, of course:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

As stated by Costas.

Answer (score -1):

```
find . -mtime +3 -type f -not -name '*pid*' |xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: This seems quite unrelated to the question at hand.