# Delete files older than 500 days

Tags: shell-script, files, find, wildcards, arguments

I have directory with files from 2010 year.. I want to delete all files older than 500 days and I tried this:

```
find /var/log/arc/* -type f -mtime +500 -delete {}\;
```

But I get this:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/find: Argument list too long
```

As I know this means that there are too many files and `find` can't handle them. But even if I put `+2000` which is 3+ years I still getting this.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239268/116858 (see also comment)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're missing that `find` doesn't need a list of files as input. The problem is that the glob `/var/log/arc/*` expands to too many files. However, `find` will recurse into subdirectories by default, so there's no need to use the glob at all:

```
find /var/log/arc/ -type f -mtime +500 -delete
```

`-delete` is a non-standard predicate. If your `find` implementation doesn't support it, you can use:

```
find /var/log/arc/ -type f -mtime +500 -exec rm -f {} +
```

instead.

Comment: Thank's but now got this: `find: invalid predicate `-delete'`

Comment: @Garg first, sorry, I just copied your command and hadn't noticed your syntax is wrong. The `-delete` doesn't take `{}`. See update. However, your error message seems to suggest that your version of `find` doesn't support `-delete`. If you're not using GNU `find` (which in most cases you won't unless you're using Linux), you need to use `-exec -rm {} \;` instead.

Comment: Thank you. `-exec rm {} \;` do the trick.

Comment: @hobbs I don't see why not, `-exec` is [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html).

Comment: @terdon my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm the current aurhot of *rawhide* (*rh*) (see https://github.com/raforg/rawhide)

What you are missing is that *find* only needs the directory (`/var/log/arc`), not all the files in that directory (`/var/log/arc/*`). Removing the `/*` and `{}\;` (which shouldn't be there) would fix it for *GNU find*. For non-*GNU find*, you also need to replace `-delete {}\;` with `-exec /bin/rm '{}' \;`.

FWIW, An alternative to *find* is my *rawhide* (*rh*) program. With it, you can do:

```
rh -UUU /var/log/arc 'f && old(500*days)'
```

It's much the same, but shorter and more readable.

`-UUU` unlinks/deletes/removes matches.

`f` (or `file`) matches regular files.

`old(500*days)` matches files modified at least 500 days ago.