# Delete files 10 days older from hdfs

Tags: hadoop

I am writing a ksh script to clean up hdfs directories and files at least 10 days old. I am testing the deletion command in a terminal, but it kept saying it is wrong:

```
$ hdfs dfs -find "/file/path/file" -depth -type d -mtime +10 -exec rm -rf {} \;
find: Unexpected argument: -depth
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete files older than X days +](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194863/delete-files-older-than-x-days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hdfs dfs` command executes the following command in a special shell that is not fully Unix compatible, some of the programs available there are like the Unix programs but others are not. The `find` program is one of them, the expressions that command understands in hdfs are only the following:

```
-name pattern
-iname pattern
-print
-print0Always
```

So the expression that you are trying out there does not work within the hdfs shell unfortunately.

Source: [The hadoop documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#find)

Answer (score 0):

Those functionalities are supported in Hadoop 2.7
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-8989