# Delete files that are older than x number of days

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have a situation where I have to clean up files that are older than 7 days, but from multiple locations like below.

```
/home/user1/Out/vendor
/home/user2/Out/vendor
/home/user3/Out/vendor
/home/user4/Out/vendor
        ︙
/home/usern/Out/vendor
```

Can someone tell me how to achieve this without deleting folders? I am thinking to call there users from a text file.

Comment: Did you have a look at `man find` yet?

Comment: This may help you https://askubuntu.com/questions/589210/removing-files-older-than-7-days

Answer (score 2):

The technique described in [Delete files older than *X* days +](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205539/80216)
will work for you:

```
find /path/to/directory/ -mtime +7 -delete
```

but it leaves out a couple of pieces of your question.

1. ... from multiple locations ...

   You can specify multiple starting points
   for a single `find` command. 
   Do

   ```
   find /home/user1/Out/vendor /home/user2/Out/vendor /home/user3/Out/vendor /home/user4/Out/vendor … /home/usern/Out/vendor -mtime +7 -delete
   ```

   or

   ```
   find /home/user1/Out/vendor /home/user2/Out/vendor /home/user3/Out/vendor \
        /home/user4/Out/vendor … /home/usern/Out/vendor -mtime +7 -delete
   ```

   for readability.

   But you don't have to explicitly list all the directories like that. 
   If you're ***literally*** dealing with
   `user1`, `user2`, ..., `usern`,
   (where *`n`* is a number), you can do

   ```
   find /home/user{1,2,3,4,…,n}/Out/vendor -mtime +7 -delete
   ```

   or even

   ```
   find /home/user{1..n}/Out/vendor -mtime +7 -delete
   ```

   (using literally two dots (**`.`**), a.k.a. period or full stop) in bash.

   But I guess you probably aren't literally dealing with
   `user1`, `user2`, ..., `usern`;
   your users probably have *names.* 
   But the same principle applies; you can do

   ```
   find /home/{user1,user2,user3,user4,…,usern}/Out/vendor -mtime +7 -delete
   ```

   For example,

   ```
   find /home/{alice,bob,cathy,david,…,nathan}/Out/vendor -mtime +7 -delete
   ```

   or even

   ```
   find ~{alice,bob,cathy,david,…,nathan}/Out/vendor -mtime +7 -delete
   ```
2. … how to achieve this without deleting folders?

   Just add `-type f` to the command:

   ```
   find /home/{user1,user2,user3,user4,…,usern}/Out/vendor -type f -mtime +7 -delete
   ```